# Cannot checkout to invalid path

Tags: git, symfony, azure

I'm trying to deploy my Symfony2 application to my Azure Web App, but I've ran in to some troubles.

When pushing to remote, I get the following messages in my Terminal

```
remote: Updating branch 'master'.
remote: Deployment failed
remote: Error - Changes committed to remote repository but deployment to website failed.
```

When I check my Azure web app, I also get a 'Deployment Failed' warning, with the following log:

```
Cannot checkout to invalid path 'app/Resources/views/gprofile/profile.html.twig'
```

This is the first time I'm really working with git and Azure, but I have no idea where to start to solve my problem.

Any help?

Comment: I can't help you with this problem but you could be interested with the official Symfony documentation : [Deploy to Miscrosoft Azure Website Cloud](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/azure-website.html)

Comment: That's what I was following.

Comment: I once tried the tutorial with a test application, and there everything worked fine, so it'll be something specific to my current app..

Comment: Try to identify step by step the main differences between your test application and your master ?

Comment: The test app was something completely unrelated to my current app, I just set it up to test committing because it was my first time working with git :)

Comment: What about this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29452787/azure-git-deploy-of-node-project-failing) ? (similar problem but other platform)

Answer (score 1):

Found my issue.

Apparently my file name had some kind of illegal character which I didn't notice until I saw it written out in Terminal.

```
app/Resources/views/profile.html\020.twig
```

Entering the name again fixed the issue and gave me a valid file.